# CSS Transform Rotate will not allow elements inside div to rotate

Tags: javascript, css, react-hooks

I am basically trying to create flashcards but with food recipes, I want to show the name and title of a recipe and once you click on the card it flips to the back showing the recipe. I'm trying to use a handleflip function and it does switch the classes from card to card-flip but it is not rotating the elements inside the div.

```
   const [flip, setFlip] = useState(false);
    const handleFlip =() => {
        setFlip(!flip);
    };

    return (
        <div className={`card ${flip ? 'card-flip' : '' }`}onClick={handleFlip}>

            <div className="front">
                <div className="card-title" >
                    <h2 >{recipecard.title}</h2>
                </div>
                <div className="card-text">
                    <p >{recipecard.description}</p>
                </div>  
            </div>

            <div className="back">
                <div className="card-title">
                    <h2 >{recipecard.title}</h2>
                </div>
                <div className="card-text">
                    <p >{recipecard.ingredients}</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

```
.card{
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid rgb(187, 178, 178);
    transform-style:preserve-3d !important; 
    transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(var(--rotate-y,0)); 
    height:450px;
    width: 450px;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease;
}
.card .card-flip{
    --rotate-y: 180deg;
}
.card .front,
.card .back {
    position:absolute;
    padding: 1rem;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.card .front{
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.card .back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Ive consoled.logged to make sure the logic is correct and it does and the class is changing when its clicked but my front div is not rotating 180deg to become invisible, the transform value from the card class is also not changing to the card-flip classes value. Ive also tried it on chrome,edge and mozilla and theres not change in how it interacts with any browser.

Comment: `.card .card-flip` would select an element with the class `card-flip`, that is a _descendant_ of an element with the class `card` - not what you have here. You want to select an element that has both classes, so the selector needs to be `.card.card-flip`, without the white space in between.

Comment: Oh ok so in the future if I want to use properties of two classes I have to combine them together but if I just want properties of one or the other I would add the space and then call the class name I want in that particular div?